# passing variables as arguments from excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code for passing arguments to my script from VBA.

Successful case: (argument value without space)

```
FilePath = "c:\Users\dimension_export.exe"
AppName = "Area_Sales"
Call Shell(FilePath & " " & AppName, 1)
```

Error case: (argument value with space (''))

```
FilePath = "c:\Users\dimension_export.exe"
AppName = "Total Sales"
Call Shell(FilePath & " " & AppName, 1)
```

when I do this, only the **Total** part in the AppName variable is passed as a argument to my exe file.

> Is there any specific keyword or symbols I should pad up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Call Shell(FilePath & " " & AppName, 1)
```

should be

```
Call Shell(FilePath & " """ & AppName &  """", 1)
```

Any items with spaces (including the file path) should be enclosed in quotes